# OData :CollectionOpenPropertyAccess not supported in DataManaged QueryNodeBinder (CollectionNode)

Tags: java, browser, odata

I am getting mentioned error :

CollectionOpenPropertyAccess not supported in DataManaged QueryNodeBinder (CollectionNode)

When Calling OData Request from Browser or Java Application.

It looks like generic error.

Can anyone here provide information what is the problem here with the call

My OData request Contains Expand, Select and Filter Clause as mentioned below :

[http://baseUrl/object1?$filter=object2/property1 eq 1 and property2 eq 2 object3/object4/any(o:o/geography/geochildren/any(c:c/ID eq 1 or ID eq 2))&$select=prop1,prop2,prop3&top=500
&expand=object2($select=propxyz),object3($expand=object5($select=property5),object6($expand=object7($select=property6),object4($select=property4);$select=prop7,prop8,prop9)&$orderby=prop10 asc](http://baseUrl/object1?$filter=object2/property1%20eq%201%20property2%20eq%202%20object3/object4/any(o:o/geography/geochildren/any(c:c/ID%20eq%201%20or%20ID%20eq%202))&$select=prop1,prop2,prop3&top=500%20&expanf=object2($select=propxyz),object3($expand=object5($select=property5),object6($expand=object7($select=property6),object4($select=property4);$select=prop7,prop8,prop9)&$orderby=prop10%20asc)

due to security reason i can not post here exact url.

What could be the issue here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was happening due to spelling issue for one of the object mentioned in Odata request.. OData requests seems to be case sensitive..

At one place it should be 'Geography' which was 'GeoGraphy'  in my case.